# How do I check if there is a certain number of characters in an answer with JavaScript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, ip

I have this website where you can upload some info and it will be stored. I currently have a validation on it, but I am trying to make it more precise. I want to be able to send an alert say... if they have more that three .(dots) in there answer. Here is what I got:

```
function ValidateContactForm()
{
    var name = document.ContactForm.sName;
    var ip = document.ContactForm.sIp;
    var port = document.ContactForm.sPort;
    var type = document.ContactForm.sType;
    var description = document.ContactForm.sDesc;
    if (name.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a server name");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (ip.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter an valid IP Address");
        ip.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (ip.value.length > 18) {
        window.alert("Please enter an valid IP Address");
        ip.focus();
        return false;
}
    if (port.value == "" || port > 4 || port < 6)
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid port number");
        port.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (description.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a description");
        description.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to make it so that if there is more than 3 dots in the IP, it will alert you. How would I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using RegExp, we can match all of the dots, and count the matches. [JSPerf of other options](http://jsperf.com/count-instances-of-a-single-character-in-a-string)

```
if ((ip.value.match(/\./g) || []).length !== 3) {
    window.alert("Please enter a valid IP address");
    ip.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `.match()` expects a single parameter that is a regex. `.match(/\./g)` would work.

Comment: (Actually I think if you supply a string it tries to convert it to a regex, but it ignores the second parameter so it doesn't do a global match.)

Comment: Correct. `arg[0]` will be converted into `new RegExp(arg[0])`, so I would have had to use `ip.value.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g"))` in the original. Switching to `.match(/\./g)` is far more logical :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
number_of_dots = ((ip.value).split(".")).length - 1
if (number_of_dots > 3){
  alert("more than 3 dots")
}
```

to get the number of the dots in the ip address

Answer (score -2):

Ip's always have 4 dots, So you wont need to hassle with 3 and 4 dot ip codes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. IP addresses have 4 _parts,_ so 3 _dots._ But in any case, we're talking here about validating user input, so there's no "always" - the user could enter anything.